# Extract specific rows based on the set cut-off values in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract

I have a TAB-delimited .txt file that looks like this.

```
Gene_name   A   B   C   D   E   F
Gene1      1    0   5   2   0   0
Gene2      4    45  0   0   32  1
Gene3      0    23  0   4   0   54
Gene4     12    0   6   8   7   4
Gene5     4     0   0   6   0   7
Gene6     0     6   8   0   0   5
Gene7     13    45  64  234 0   6
Gene8     11    6   0   7   7   9
Gene9      6    0   12  34  0   11
Gene10    23    4   6   7   89  0
```

I want to extract rows in which at least 3 columns have values > 0..
How do I do this using pandas? I am clueless about how to use conditions in .txt files.

thanks very much!

---

update: adding on to this question, how do I analyze specific columns for this conditon.. let's say I look into column A, C, E & F and then extract rows that have at least 3 of these columns with values >5.

cheers!

Comment: Once you load them with pandas they are no longer txt files, instead they become `DataFrames`. If you follow a tutorial/guide about pandas you will find how to fillter data.

Comment: thanks for editing this question, just wondering how did you get the thing in tabular form? thanks..

Comment: @Edin You copy the data and hit ctrl+K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piggy backing off of @MaxU solution, I like go ahead put 'gene_name' into the index not worry about all that index slicing:

```
df = pd.read_csv(tfile, delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0)
df[df.gt(0).sum(1).ge(3)]
```

#### Edit for question update:

```
df[df[['A','C','E','F']].gt(5).sum(1).ge(3)]
```

Output:

```
            A   B   C    D   E   F
Gene_name                         
Gene4      12   0   6    8   7   4
Gene7      13  45  64  234   0   6
Gene8      11   6   0    7   7   9
Gene9       6   0  12   34   0  11
Gene10     23   4   6    7  89   0
```

Comment: Nice idea! It makes solution look pretty!

Comment: @Scott Boston could you please help with the updated question:

Comment: @Edin  See update to the solution.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @ScottBoston yes, that works brilliantly. Coul you please explain briefly how this code works, would be very helpful to write next time on my own.

Comment: Sure it is using df[['A','C','E','F']] is basically column filtering the original dataframe.  Then I check each value is greater than 5, that returns a dataframe of True and False, then I sum accross each row (axis=1) and check to see if that sum is greater than or equal to 5.   That returns as series with the row index of the original dataframe as the index of the series.  Next, using boolean indexing on the original dataframe, I pass that series back to the dataframe to select on those rows where the series is True.   Break that statement up in parts.  Start with the inner df.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True)

In [22]: df[df.select_dtypes(['number']).gt(0).sum(axis=1).ge(3)]
Out[22]:
  Gene_name   A   B   C    D   E   F
0     Gene1   1   0   5    2   0   0
1     Gene2   4  45   0    0  32   1
2     Gene3   0  23   0    4   0  54
3     Gene4  12   0   6    8   7   4
4     Gene5   4   0   0    6   0   7
5     Gene6   0   6   8    0   0   5
6     Gene7  13  45  64  234   0   6
7     Gene8  11   6   0    7   7   9
8     Gene9   6   0  12   34   0  11
9    Gene10  23   4   6    7  89   0
```

some explanation:

```
In [25]: df.select_dtypes(['number']).gt(0)
Out[25]:
       A      B      C      D      E      F
0   True  False   True   True  False  False
1   True   True  False  False   True   True
2  False   True  False   True  False   True
3   True  False   True   True   True   True
4   True  False  False   True  False   True
5  False   True   True  False  False   True
6   True   True   True   True  False   True
7   True   True  False   True   True   True
8   True  False   True   True  False   True
9   True   True   True   True   True  False

In [26]: df.select_dtypes(['number']).gt(0).sum(axis=1)
Out[26]:
0    3
1    4
2    3
3    5
4    3
5    3
6    5
7    5
8    4
9    5
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Using operators (as a complement to Max's answer):

```
mask = (df.iloc[:, 1:] > 0).sum(1) >= 3    
mask

0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
7    True
8    True
9    True
dtype: bool

df[mask] 
  Gene_name   A   B   C    D   E   F
0     Gene1   1   0   5    2   0   0
1     Gene2   4  45   0    0  32   1
2     Gene3   0  23   0    4   0  54
3     Gene4  12   0   6    8   7   4
4     Gene5   4   0   0    6   0   7
5     Gene6   0   6   8    0   0   5
6     Gene7  13  45  64  234   0   6
7     Gene8  11   6   0    7   7   9
8     Gene9   6   0  12   34   0  11
9    Gene10  23   4   6    7  89   0
```

---

Similarly, querying all rows with 5 or more positive values:

```
df[(df.iloc[:, 1:] > 0).sum(1) >= 5]

  Gene_name   A   B   C    D   E  F
3     Gene4  12   0   6    8   7  4
6     Gene7  13  45  64  234   0  6
7     Gene8  11   6   0    7   7  9
9    Gene10  23   4   6    7  89  0
```

Comment: @coldspeed just adding on to this question, how do I analyze specific columns for this conditon.. let's say I look into column A, C, E & F and then extract rows that have at least 3 of these columns with values >0.

Comment: apologies I am naive to this but when I run this: import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('python1.txt', sep='\t')
df2 = df[['A', 'C', 'E', 'F']]; df2[(df2.iloc[:, 1:] > 0).sum(1) >= 3]
print(df2)     I get rows with all four columns with values in them.. I was hoping to get only those rows which had at least three columns (of A, C, E, F) with values >0

Comment: @Edin Sorry it's `df2 = df[['A', 'C', 'E', 'F']]; df2[(df2 > 0).sum(1) >= 3]`

Comment: @coldspeed It still gives me all rows regardless of values in these columns, it doesn't even bother when I change " >= 3 " to ">= 5".

Comment: @Edin Based on your update: `df2 = df[['A', 'C', 'E', 'F']]; df2[(df2 > 5).sum(1) >= 3]`